# Visual Studio 2008 vs Visual Studio 2010 on Framework 3.5

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2008 since its release, but I have never ever use Visual Studio 2010. Basically I want to know where VS 2010 is a only a other version of Visual Studio or it has some special features.

I have to work in only .NET framework version 3.5 not 4.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Upgrade Advice 2008 / 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402978/visual-studio-upgrade-advice-2008-2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop/target your applications to the 3.5 framework with Visual Studio.

Visual Studio 2010 of course offers a better development experience. Here are those items that I'd highlight to justify the switch:

- better TFS 2010 integrations
- nicer font rendering
- Start Page improvements (pinning projects and no more useless RSS feeds)
- easier path to revving to beyond .NET 3.5
- much improved extensibility and the [Visual Studio Gallery integration](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/)

Comment: I would definitely use VS 2010 even if I had to target the 3.5 framework. The experience is 10 times better and the platform feels much more stable, and includes better deployment options.

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2010 you can use great free extension pack: Power Tools. You can read more about it on Scott Guthrie blog:: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/09/visual-studio-2010-productivity-power-tool-extensions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth going to VS2010 if only for [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) and [Web.Config transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx).  I'd also suggest going to .NET 4/MVC3 as well, which would require VS2010.  But it's worth doing even without that as an immediate benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced VS2010 is better than VS2008 if you're only developing, for instance, using ASP.NET and WinForms, for .NET 3.5.

Compiling for Framework 3.5 and x86 on Windows 7 x64 is a nightmare due to the [Resgen](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/e5900710-9849-4d10-aa28-48b734d06bf2) problem, where the workarounds don't always work (I went back to Windows 7 x86 because of this).  (Anyone know whether this is fixed with the respective Windows 7 and VS2010 SP1s?)

I'm not clear why, but opening a Winforms designer often fails, requiring a restart of VS and a reload of the solution.  This is incredibly irritating.

And the toolbar customisation isn't as nice in VS2010.

I should think that if you want the Framework 4.0 features, or if you're working with Silverlight or WPF, VS2010 is much better.

But otherwise, I don't think the advantages are that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just Choose your target framework when creating your project in vs 2010.

Same post here:

[how to add .net 3.5 to visual studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603560/how-to-add-net-3-5-to-visual-studio-2010)

[Can I develop asp.net 3.5/2.0 projects using Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891507/can-i-develop-asp-net-3-5-2-0-projects-using-visual-studio-2010)

Or Try to install .net framework 3.5 and install its update[.net framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959209)

Regards